# grouping data for ggplot using rep function

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have 2068 rows with 47 unique names. Meaning each name has 44 rows. I want to group the names in a bunch of 4 so that the last bunch has 3 names. When try this by using the code as `tbl$GRP <- rep(1:11, each=44)`. It gives the error as

```
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, GRP, value = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,  : replacement has 484 rows, data has 2068
```

This is needed as I am using `GRP` variable for 11 facets of ggplot2 where 4 line graphs for each bunch are displayed except the last one which will display the graph for the last 3 names.

Answer (score 0):

I guess I got a workaround as follows:

```
tbl$GRP <- c(rep(1:11, each=176), rep(12, 132))
```